# Use array element as termination in for loop

Tags: java

Please explain this loop:

```
for(p=0;p<a[j];p++)
```

I am a beginner and I am confused how do such loops work?

Please emphasize on use of `a[j]` in loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `a[j]` remains a constant positive number through each iteration of the `for` loop, the loop will run exactly `a[j]` times, where `a[j]` evaluates to some `integer` (or `long`, we can't tell from the code posted). Of course `a[j]` (or `j`) could be modified inside the loop. In any case, the loop terminates once `p` is greater than or equal to `a[j]` when the loop condition is evaluated. The condition is checked before each iteration of the loop. If `a[j]` is zero or a negative number, the contents of the `for` loop are never executed. The loop can also exit prematurely at any time if there is a call to `break` or `return` within the loop.

Comment: `... the loop will run exactly a[j] times ...` is not true for all cases. What if `a[j]` is negative ? Of course, a loop cannot run for negative number of times.

Answer (score 1):

You're obviously a beginner, so I'll lay it out.

The variable `a` holds an object that is an *array* of `int`, and `j` is an `int`. The code that preceded this snippet probably looked something like this:

```
int j = 5; // for example
int[] a = new int[10]; // An array of 10 ints
a[5] = 3; // somewhere, the jth element of a should have been assigned
```

Within this context, `a[j]` is `3`, so the loop would ***initially*** be the same as:

```
for (p=0; p<3; p++)
```

The reason I say "initially" is that code within the loop may alter `a[5]` and thus change the loop termination condition to a number other than `3`

Note to nitpickers: for "int" you may read any of the java numeric primatives.

Comment: `for (p=0; p<3; p++)` is _not_ the same as `for (p=0; p<a[5]; p++)` because `a[5]` can change inside the loop but `3` cannot.

Comment: The guy obviously needed some basic help, so I was trying to keep it simple, but as usual people feel the need to nitpick. Fine - I'll edit the answer

Comment: I think the fact that `a[j]` is non-constant is the crux of the whole question. Why else would you write a loop like that?

Comment: I agree that the loop seems a little flaky, but there may be legitimate reasons for it. We just can't tell from the tiny snippet of code shown. you could be right - we'll never know.